# Hitting an endpoint from a text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, service, textbox, endpoint

I am new at coding with C# and I am currently developing an application to monitor response times (and other things) by hitting a service.

My application has a input text box where the user can input the address of the endpoint, then I want to collect the soapActions, so the button next to the text 
box is called "Get soapActions."

I have the code to hit the endpoint and I will be storing the XML in a database I also created... But by question now follows.

How am I able to take the input from the user in the text box use that address to use my "hit the endpoint" code?

Thank you all in advance, sorry if this too basic or confusing in advance. Would be a lot if I could get an answer, thank you!

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: @rene, the question is being asked in the fourth "paragraph". I have however received an answer and come to a conclusion, thank you for your "concern" for my problem.

Comment: You're welcome, always happy to help. Do know that self-answering is encouraged, as explained in the [help]. That way future visitors might also be served when they have a similar idea or question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing some complexity here, or did not fully understand your question.  But if this is a WPF or UWP application you are building you can simply access the `Text` property on the textbox.  In code-behind (xaml.cs files) you can access the property by using the `x:Name` you assigned to the text box in your view code (.xaml file).  So if you had a `<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox"...` you can access the value of it in code behind with `string endpoint = MyTextBox.Text;`

Comment: Hey @Shayon! Thank you for etting around to replying! I was able to answer my own question and you weren't far off. Thank you again!